# Form is returned with HTML tags (for use as a template)

Tags: php, html, forms, output

I would like to make a form where users can enter text, and when the form is submitted it will return an output in HTML. The form is for use by me and my colleagues, not end users. We are looking for this solution in order to better style our website's content. We use Wordpress but have failed to find a solution to this issue. (We currently use a basic HTML template, but that makes for time-consuming work when you look at the example below).
Here's how I envisage this form:

```
<form>
Artist name: <input type="text" name="artist"><br />
Track name: <input type="text" name="track"><br />
Artist link: <input type="text" name="artistlink"><br />
Lyrics name: <input type="text" name="lyrics">br />
</form>
```

I can do the above part fine. Then the more complicated is making the output contain HTML tags. I want something like this:

```
<strong>Artist:</strong> <div id="artistname">artist's name</div>
<strong>Track:</strong> <div id="trackname>track name</div>
<strong>Lyrics:</strong> <div id="lyricstext" style="overflow: auto; height: 360px;    width: 640px;">
<ul>
<ul>
<li>Its the two kids</li>
<li>New shit improving the movement</li>
<li>We prove this with music</li>
<li>Words for the chosing</li>
</ul>
</ul>
</div>
```

This way, I can add a jQuery snippet like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("ul li:nth-child("odd")").addClass("even");
  });
</script>
```

To be able to style the odd and even `<li>` differently. I also have greater control over each aspect of the output by creating divs for each part.
I essentially need this as a template for putting our content on the site.
Hope my question is understandable!
Thanks.

Comment: Show some effort and show what you have so far in PHP

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
<form method="POST" action="">
  Artist name: <input type="text" name="artist"><br />
  Track name: <input type="text" name="track"><br />
  Artist link: <input type="text" name="artistlink"><br />
  Lyrics name: <input type="text" name="lyrics"><br />
  <input type="submit" value="OK" />
</form> 

<?php
  //check if the submit button has been pressed and if the artist value is not empty 
  if(isset($_POST['artist']) && $_POST['artist'] != "") {
    echo '<strong>Artist:</strong><div id="artistname>"'.$_POST['artist'].'</div>';
  }
?>
```